# Firebase Web / Uploading file to Firebase Storage Not Working

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-storage, addeventlistener

I've watched 'Getting Started with Firebase Storage on the Web' on YouTube. I applied it to my code, and it worked perfectly. But I wanted uploading step separately from selecting file step. So I created upload button and added event listener to the button. (Thus, I basecally separated the code from the video into two event listener functions because, again, I wanted selecting a file and uploading the file two separate actions).

I really don't understand why it's not working. It doesn't give me any error on my log console. Could anybody please tell me WHY this is not working and HOW I can fix this? Thank you.

```js
var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
var fileButton = document.getElementById('fileButton');
var uploadButton = document.getElementById('uploadButton');
var file;

fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    file = e.target.files[0];
});


uploadButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var fileName = file.name;
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('images/' + fileName);
    var task = storageRef.put(file);

    task.on('state_changed',
        function progress(snapshot) {
            var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred/snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            uploader.value = percentage;
        },
        function error(err) {

        },
        function complete() {

        }
    );

    window.alert('Upload Done');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the docs do not use **named functions** inside the callbacks, how about converting them into **anonymous functions**?

And also, how can you be sure that there isn't an error if you are not using `console.log()` on the error callback...

Remember that the console will not be displaying any error if it's not handle by the console methods

[Firebase Upload Files - Monitor Upload Progress](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress)

Comment: Inside callbacks, so you mean changing function progress(snapshot) into function(snapshot), for example?

Comment: Yep, I'm not hoping that works 100%, but is worth to try, the other thing is to add the `console.error()` to the error function